# generating permutations

Tags: algorithms, permutations

I have been using this method of exchanging consecutive indexes to generate permutations, but don't know what this algorithm is called. Tried to google search but couldn't find.

Method-

```
while(current_perm != start_perm) {
        current_perm = exchange ith place with i+1th ;
        increment i ;
        i = i % length of string ;  
}
```

e.g.
1 2 3 -> 2 1 3 -> 2 3 1 -> 1 3 2 -> 3 1 2 -> 3 2 1 -> 1 2 3

once we reach the starting permutation 1 2 3 we stop.

Answer (score 0):

Doing a Bing search for *algorithm for generating permutations* I came up with [Heap's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Yes, I had also found heap's algorithm , but the order in which the elements are interchanged in both algorithms is different.